# how to make livereload load the entire page

Tags: livereload

I need to make the livereload load the entire page when there is a change in the server side page. right now I am passing the file that got changed. So how to make it to load the entire page.

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question. In fact if you need to reload the complete page, you can use a simple redirect and just reload everything. 

Livereload is defined as reloading parts of the page without reloading the whole page. But if you need to reload everything there is no point in a livereload, is it?

Comment: server side template changes..then you need to reload the entire page

Answer (score 1):

What're your options in the watch list? In particular, have you set `livereload:true` or `spawn:false` anywhere?

The people [on this thread](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/87) are trying to prevent a browser refresh being forced, so may be of use to you...